# Flutter: FCM background notification large icon

Tags: flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using firebase_messaging and flutter_local_notifications for notifications, and I was able to show a large icon in case of local(foreground) notifications, but I didn't seem to find a way to show the same large icon when the app is background.
[image: foreground]

[image: background]

Answer (score 0):

handle background noti and show noti using local notification.

`FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);`

Answer (score -1):

This code help you to receive a Notification and to use in your app :

```
void initMessaging() {
var androiInit = AndroidInitializationSettings(‘@mipmap/ic_launcher’);//for logo
  var iosInit = IOSInitializationSettings();
  var initSetting=InitializationSettings(android: androiInit,iOS:
   iosInit);
  fltNotification = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
  fltNotification.initialize(initSetting);
  var androidDetails =
   AndroidNotificationDetails(‘1’, ‘channelName’, ‘channel 
    Description’);
  var iosDetails = IOSNotificationDetails();
  var generalNotificationDetails =
   NotificationDetails(android: androidDetails, iOS: iosDetails);
FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {     RemoteNotification notification=message.notification;
   AndroidNotification android=message.notification?.android;
   if(notification!=null && android!=null){
     fltNotification.show(
       notification.hashCode, notification.title, notification.
       body, generalNotificationDetails);
}
});
}
```

If you have any difficulty, please check this article : [Flutter Push Notification Medium](https://medium.com/geekculture/push-notification-in-flutter-in-background-as-well-as-foreground-using-firebase-1e6e7ecad292).
Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but my question was about large-icon, not that I can't implement notifications in general.

Answer (score -1):

A better way to use `largeIcon` is using the image property in notification payload when you are sending the notification:

```
const payload = {
  notification: {
    title: 'title',
    body: 'description',
    image: 'large_icon_url',
    sound : "default"
  },
};
```

Comment: this is not the `largeIcon`. it's just a plain attachment image.

Answer (score -1):

1- use flutter_local_notifications in backgroundMessageHandler to display the image

2- remove the "notification" in the payload and add your data in
"data:{
title: 'title',
body: 'description',
image: 'image',
}"